# Plot areas by class in a polygon with Google Earth Engine

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, classification, chart, count

I would like to plot the number of pixels or the area for each class contained in a polygon (shape of a country). I have found the `ui.Chart.image.byClass` function but I don't understand how to use it with only one raster

for example :

```js
// load
var landCover = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1');
var country = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
// filter
var sn = country.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Senegal'));
// filter on image for 2017 and clip with country shape
var modis2017 = ee.Image(landCover.filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-01')
                .select('LC_Prop1')
                .first()).clip(sn);



// display
Map.addLayer(sn, {}, 'country');
//Map.addLayer(country, {}, 'country');
Map.addLayer(modis2017, {}, 'raster');
```

Comment: Why would you like to calculate the amount of pixels inside each country? This requires a huge aggregation of pixels which would run out of memory easily.

Comment: @Kuik , my purpose is to know for each class of the raster the area for a specific country (Senegal in my example).  `MODIS/006/MCD12Q1` data contain 16 class so I would like to have a table (or barplot) with the number of pixel for each class in Senegal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick overview of the amount of pixels each class has inside your area of interest (sn), you should use the histogram chart:

- **Update:** results in an array added with the full code

```js
// load
var landCover = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1');
var country = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
// filter
var sn = country.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Senegal'));
print(sn)

// filter on image for 2017 and clip with country shape
var modis2017 = ee.Image(landCover.filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-01')
            .select('LC_Prop1')
            .first()); //.clip(sn);
print(modis2017)

// quick plot the amount of pixels in a histogram
var graph = ui.Chart.image.histogram(modis2017, sn, 500).setOptions({
  title: 'Histogram ## pixels for each class',
});
print(graph);

// get the results in an array
var values = ee.List(modis2017.get('LC_Prop1_class_values'));
var array = values.map(function(value){
  var cstImage = ee.Image.constant(value);
  var equals = modis2017.eq(cstImage);
  return equals.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), sn.geometry(), 500).values();
})

print(array)

// display
Map.addLayer(sn, {}, 'country');
//Map.addLayer(country, {}, 'country');
Map.addLayer(modis2017, {}, 'raster');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d9bf71c4aa94943d1fabd6cd659632a3

Comment: If I want those result in an array? How can I do that?

Comment: I added the full code to do so. You will see that small amounts of pixels are now also taken into consideration.
Also note that values can slightly differ, possibly because the pixels are partly in the region of interest

Comment: me again! I'm trying to save the `array` with 
`Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: array,
  description:'test1',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});` but I don't understand the object array ! Why it's wrong ?